# Finding all possible paths from one node to another?

Tags: c#, graph, breadth-first-search

I was trying to find all possible paths, but I am having hard time keeping track of the paths that I have visited.  Here is the code so far:

```
public void FindAllPaths(Node startNode, Node endNode)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(startNode);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentNode = queue.Dequeue();

            foreach (var edge in currentNode.Edges)
            {
                if (edge.Visisted)
                    continue;

                edge.Visisted = true;
                queue.Enqueue(edge.TargetNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you go A-B-C-E then C will be marked as visited, but since C is also part of the path A-D-C-E you won't be able to find the later.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Yes, I realied that, so am unsure what do do?  I first had the Visited property on the Node, but if I have already visited that node, it won't go on, then I decided to put it on the Edge, but if I have already visited that edge, it won't go on.

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep track of the paths visited for each route, not globally. For a breadth first approach each route needs a list of visited paths. For a depth first approach you can either keep a list of visited paths, or keep it global but unvisit the paths as you backtrack.

Getting the length of the path and the total weight will more or less do itself, once you keep track of the paths for each route.

With your current algorithm you would enqueue an item that has a node and a list of visited paths:

```
public void FindAllPaths(Node startNode, Node endNode) {
  queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(startNode, new List<Edge>()));
  while (queue.Count > 0) {
    var currentItem = queue.Dequeue();
    foreach (var edge in currentItem.Node.Edges) {
      if (!currentItem.Visited.Contains(edge)) {
        List<Edge> visited = new List<Edge>(currentItem.Visited);
        visited.Add(edge);
        if (edge.TargetNode == endNode) {
          // visited.Count is the path length
          // visited.Sum(e => e.Weight) is the total weight
        } else {
          queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(edge.TargetNode, visited));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The QueueItem class is just:

```
public class QueueItem {

  public Node Node { get; private set; }
  public List<Edge> Visited { get; private set; }

  public QueueItem(Node node, List<Edge> visited) {
    Node = node;
    Visited = visited;
  }

}
```

I set up the paths this way:

```
Node a = new Node("A");
Node b = new Node("B");
Node c = new Node("C");
Node d = new Node("D");
Node e = new Node("E");

a.Edges.Add(new Edge(5, b));
a.Edges.Add(new Edge(7, e));
a.Edges.Add(new Edge(5, d));
b.Edges.Add(new Edge(4, c));
c.Edges.Add(new Edge(2, e));
c.Edges.Add(new Edge(8, d));
d.Edges.Add(new Edge(8, c));
d.Edges.Add(new Edge(6, e));
e.Edges.Add(new Edge(3, b));
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not globally?  Do you have an example?

Comment: @xaisoft: If you have `Visited` as a property of `Edge`, then each path can only be visited once, when you try a different route the paths from the previous route will be visited already.

Comment: Yes, I actually ran into it.  If I put the Visited property on a Node, the same thing happens as well.  Not sure what to do?

Comment: @xaisoft: If you keep a list of visited paths for the route (neither in the nodes nor the edges), you would check if a path is in that list to find out if it is visited. You can also keep the `Visited` property as is, but then you need to use a depth-first algorithm that steps back and resets the `Visited` property before trying a different path.

Comment: OK, I somewhat understand, but it is the implementation that is throwing me off, so are you saying that if I continue with BFS, I don't need a visited property and I need to basically store a List of paths?  How do I store the visited paths for the route?

Comment: @xaisoft: Yes, exactly. You can keep a list of `Edge` references, that would work as a list of paths. Instead of enqueueing nodes, you would enqueue an object that contains a node and a list of paths. When enqueing a new item, you would make a copy of the current list of paths and add the new path to it.

Comment: @xaisoft:Instead of adding "node" to the queue add {node, path_to_current.Concat(target) }  so you will have all paths in the queue.

Comment: @xaisoft: That's a class that has a node and a list of edges, I can add it to the code.

Comment: @Guffa, How could I print the paths out meaning what part of the code would I do that?

Comment: @xaisoft: I put comments in the code inside the check for the end node on how to get some information about the path. That's the place in the code where you would print the path out (or add it to a list to print it out later).

Comment: @Guffa - I got the path to print out, but I noticed a couple issues:  The Path `C` to `C` does not print all paths and `C->E->B->C` should have a total weight of 9, but its only showing 5.  I will show my code for showing the path.

Comment: @xaisoft: My bad, there is an error in the code. `List<Edge> visited = new List<Edge>(currentItem.Edges);` should be `List<Edge> visited = new List<Edge>(currentItem.Visited);`.

Comment: @Guffa - I modified the code as you stated above, but it still has the same result.

Comment: @xaisoft: I get the expected result when I test it. I added the nodes and edges that I use above.

Comment: @Guffa - Hi, Thanks for the help so far. I posted all my classes and the main program because something is still not right.  I am getting the correct number of paths now by adding 1 to my count variable, but `A->B->C` should have a total weight of 9, but it is only showing 5, I suspect this has to do that it is leaving out the weight for B->C, but not sure how to handle it.  Also finding all paths from C to C should have a lot of paths, but I only see 3 paths, for example, one missing is: `C->E->B->C->E->B->C`

Comment: @xaisoft: You are using `currentItem.Visited` to get the route, use the variable `visited` instead that contains that last path also. There are only three possible routes from C to C. The route `C->E->B->C->E->B->C` is not included because you arrive at C already with `C->E->B->C`.

Comment: @Guffa, Yes, I actually updated my posted to go through visited instead of currentItem.Visisted.  How could I modify code so the path to goes through `C->E->B->C->B->C`?

Comment: @xaisoft: That depends on why you would want the route `C->E->B->C->B->C` included. If you remove the check for visited paths and rearrange the code so that it enqueues the node even when you arrive at the target node, it will include that route. However, it will never return as the number of routes becomes infinite.

Comment: @Guffa - Would it be possible to modify your code to show that?  thanks

Comment: @xaisoft: No, that's not possible. Theoretically that route will be included, but in practice the code runs into an infinite loop before you get to that route.

Comment: @Guffa - Yes, I tried it lol and it never stopped. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you go A-B-C-E then C will be marked as visited, but since C is also part of the path A-D-C-E you won't be able to find the later. Therefore a depth-first approach seems more appropriate, as it allows you to work on one path at a time. After you are finished with a path, you can clear the Visited-flags and continue with another path. I'm trying to scetch a solution in pseudo code:

```
declare path as list of node;

procedure FindPath(node)
    for each edge in node.Edges
        if not edge.Visited then 
            edge.Visited = true
            path.Append(edge.TargetNode)
            if edge.TargetNode = goal then
                Print(path)
            else
                FindPath(edge.TargetNode)
            end
            path.Remove(edge.TargetNode)
            edge.Visited = false
        end
    end
end
```

Where `goal` is node `E` in your example. You would call `FindPath` with the start node

```
FindPath(A);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously, maintaining a `Visited` property on each edge will not work because a given edge may be present in multiple distinct paths. For example, the D/E edge will be traversed for both the A->D->E path and the A->B->C->D->E path.

You need to maintain the current path for each node added to the queue:

```
IEnumerable<Path> FindAllPaths(Node from, Node to)
{
    Queue<Tuple<Node, List<Node>>> nodes = new Queue<Tuple<Node, List<Node>>>();
    nodes.Enqueue(new Tuple<Node, List<Node>>(from, new List<Node>()));
    List<Path> paths = new List<Path>();

    while(nodes.Any())
    {
        var current = nodes.Dequeue();
        Node currentNode = current.Item1;

        if (current.Item2.Contains(currentNode))
        {
            continue;
        }

        current.Item2.Add(currentNode);

        if (currentNode == to)
        {
            paths.Add(new Path(current.Item2));
            continue;
        }

        foreach(var edge in current.Item1.Edges)
        {
            nodes.Enqueue(new Tuple<Node, List<Node>>(edge.Target, new List<Node>(current.Item2)));
        }
    }

    return paths;
}
```

Comment: What structure is Path supposed to be in List<Path>?

Comment: A path is an ordered list of nodes to get from A to E.