# Searching for all routes in a graph C#

Tags: c#

Hy guys!
I have a project where I need to find out if you can make gold from iron. The way it is is that each material is represented with a number from 1-200 and a catalisator which makes one material from an other with letters (A-Z). They experiment and store the records in a txt files. Each records looks like this: material1 catalisator material2. So this is basically a graph where every material is a vertex and every catalisator is an edge. The task is to read the txt files and create an other one with the necessary edges from iron(represented with 1) to gold(represented with 0). My current state is that I have a class called Beeolvaso:

```
class Beolvaso
{
    public int anyag1;
    public int anyag2;
    public string katalizator;
    public bool tovabbMehete;
    public int Anyag1
    {
        get
        {
            return anyag1;
        }
        set
        {
            anyag1 = value;
        }
    }
    public bool TovabbMehete
    {
        get
        {
            return tovabbMehete;
        }
        set
        {
            tovabbMehete = value;
        }
    }
    public int Anyag2
    {
        get
        {
            return anyag2;
        }
        set
        {
            anyag2 = value;
        }
    }
    public string Katalizator
    {
        get
        {
            return katalizator;
        }
        set
        {
            katalizator = value;
        }
    }
    public Beolvaso(int anyag1, string katalizator, int anyag2, bool tovabbMehete)
    {
        this.anyag1 = anyag1;
        this.anyag2 = anyag2;
        this.katalizator = katalizator;
        this.tovabbMehete = tovabbMehete;
    }
```

it basiacally stores material1 material2 catalisator and a boolean which tells us if we can continoue from material2 to an other material or not.
I have an array containing serials of these Beolvaso classes I created that stores the data from the text in a structure and I need an algorithm that iterates through the records and return all the possible routes(serial of catalisators) from 1(iron) to 0(gold). I looked up different graph searches like DFS or BFS but I need an algorith specifically for that case. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206682/finding-all-possible-paths-from-one-node-to-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible paths from one node to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206682/finding-all-possible-paths-from-one-node-to-another)

Comment: Guys if its a duplicate than can you tell meg how I get all the datas from the txt to nodes like in the example?