# c# shortest path algorithm options

Tags: c#, search, tree, heuristics

I am trying to work out how to implement a shortest path algorithm. I'm not sure which is most appropriate and could use some guidance in how I go about it.

I have a list of lines that make up my network. A line consists of 2 or more Latitude/Longitude points (LatLng). i.e. `IEnumerable<LatLng[]> networkLines.`

Here is an example of what my line network may look like graphically. Lets say the two lines in red are out starting and finishing points. The small black lines are examples of where the lines may start and stop, each may then have a number of points between that plot it along it's course.

[image]

Any advice on how I go about this would be amazing?

I have tried to implement a way to calculate if the lines are connected, as there's a chance they may not be. I'm not sure if it will help but I will include below for context.

```
// Number of steps or iterations
var numberOfSteps = 1;

// Lines connected to SiteLogger1
var connectedLines =
    lineNetworkCoordinates.Where(line => line.Any(coord => sourceLine.Any(x => x.Latitude == coord.Latitude && x.Longitude == coord.Longitude))
    && line != sourceLine);

// Keep a track of lines that have been spanned
List<LatLng[]> previouslySpannedLines = connectedLines.ToList();

// Iterate over network for number of steps set
while (numberOfSteps < maxNumberOfSteps)
{
    // Set the current connected lines to not be any that are in the previously spanned collection 
    // and also have lat/lng that meet one of the new collections
    connectedLines =
        lineNetworkCoordinates.Where(line => !previouslySpannedLines.Contains(line, new LatLngArrayComparer())
        && line.Any(coord => previouslySpannedLines.SelectMany(x => x).Any(x => x.Latitude == coord.Latitude && x.Longitude == coord.Longitude)));

    // If the SiteLogger2's line exists in collection then it's successful
    if (connectedLines.Contains(destinationLine, new LatLngArrayComparer()))
    {
        return true;
    }

    previouslySpannedLines.AddRange(connectedLines);
    numberOfSteps++;
}

return false;
```

SOLUTION:

Solution was found using a slight modification of https://gist.github.com/keithcollins/307c3335308fea62db2731265ab44c06

For future reference, this is the code I modified to work for what I needed:

```
public class PriorityQueue<T>
{
    // From Red Blob: I'm using an unsorted array for this example, but ideally this
    // would be a binary heap. Find a binary heap class:
    // * https://bitbucket.org/BlueRaja/high-speed-priority-queue-for-c/wiki/Home
    // * http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/01/priority-queues-with-c.aspx
    // * http://xfleury.github.io/graphsearch.html
    // * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net

    private List<KeyValuePair<T, float>> elements = new List<KeyValuePair<T, float>>();

    public int Count
    {
        get { return elements.Count; }
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item, float priority)
    {
        elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<T, float>(item, priority));
    }

    // Returns the Location that has the lowest priority
    public T Dequeue()
    {
        int bestIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
        {
            if (elements[i].Value < elements[bestIndex].Value)
            {
                bestIndex = i;
            }
        }

        T bestItem = elements[bestIndex].Key;
        elements.RemoveAt(bestIndex);
        return bestItem;
    }
}

public class AStarSearch
{
    // Someone suggested making this a 2d field.
    // That will be worth looking at if you run into performance issues.
    public Dictionary<LatLng[], LatLng[]> cameFrom = new Dictionary<LatLng[], LatLng[]>();
    public Dictionary<LatLng[], float> costSoFar = new Dictionary<LatLng[], float>();

    private LatLng[] start;
    private LatLng[] goal;

    static public float Heuristic(LatLng[] a, LatLng[] b)
    {
        return MapCoordinate.FindLineDistance(a) + MapCoordinate.FindLineDistance(b);
    }

    // Conduct the A* search
    public AStarSearch(IEnumerable<LatLng[]> graph, LatLng[] start, LatLng[] goal)
    {
        // start is current sprite Location
        this.start = start;
        // goal is sprite destination eg tile user clicked on
        this.goal = goal;

        // add the cross product of the start to goal and tile to goal vectors
        // Vector3 startToGoalV = Vector3.Cross(start.vector3,goal.vector3);
        // Location startToGoal = new Location(startToGoalV);
        // Vector3 neighborToGoalV = Vector3.Cross(neighbor.vector3,goal.vector3);

        // frontier is a List of key-value pairs:
        // Location, (float) priority
        var frontier = new PriorityQueue<LatLng[]>();

        // Add the starting location to the frontier with a priority of 0
        frontier.Enqueue(start, 0f);

        cameFrom.Add(start, start); // is set to start, None in example
        costSoFar.Add(start, 0f);

        while (frontier.Count > 0f)
        {
            // Get the Location from the frontier that has the lowest
            // priority, then remove that Location from the frontier
            LatLng[] current = frontier.Dequeue();

            // If we're at the goal Location, stop looking.
            if (current.Equals(goal)) break;

            // Neighbors will return a List of valid tile Locations
            // that are next to, diagonal to, above or below current
            foreach (var neighbor in graph.Where(line => line.Any(coord => current.Any(x => x.Latitude == coord.Latitude && x.Longitude == coord.Longitude))
                && line != current).ToList())
            {

                // If neighbor is diagonal to current, graph.Cost(current,neighbor)
                // will return Sqrt(2). Otherwise it will return only the cost of
                // the neighbor, which depends on its type, as set in the TileType enum.
                // So if this is a normal floor tile (1) and it's neighbor is an
                // adjacent (not diagonal) floor tile (1), newCost will be 2,
                // or if the neighbor is diagonal, 1+Sqrt(2). And that will be the
                // value assigned to costSoFar[neighbor] below.
                float newCost = costSoFar[current] + MapCoordinate.FindLineDistance(neighbor);

                // If there's no cost assigned to the neighbor yet, or if the new
                // cost is lower than the assigned one, add newCost for this neighbor
                if (!costSoFar.ContainsKey(neighbor) || newCost < costSoFar[neighbor])
                {

                    // If we're replacing the previous cost, remove it
                    if (costSoFar.ContainsKey(neighbor))
                    {
                        costSoFar.Remove(neighbor);
                        cameFrom.Remove(neighbor);
                    }

                    costSoFar.Add(neighbor, newCost);
                    cameFrom.Add(neighbor, current);
                    float priority = newCost + Heuristic(neighbor, goal);
                    frontier.Enqueue(neighbor, priority);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Return a List of Locations representing the found path
    public List<LatLng[]> FindPath()
    {

        List<LatLng[]> path = new List<LatLng[]>();
        LatLng[] current = goal;
        // path.Add(current);

        while (!current.Equals(start))
        {
            if (!cameFrom.ContainsKey(current))
            {
                //MonoBehaviour.print("cameFrom does not contain current.");
                return new List<LatLng[]>();
            }
            path.Add(current);
            current = cameFrom[current];
        }
        // path.Add(start);
        path.Reverse();
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: There are lots and lots of different shortest path algorithms, a couple off the top of my head are Dijkstra's and A*. Both of which have lots of material on them online, and aren't very hard to implement.

Comment: While outside the scope of an SO question - My suggestion would be a queue system that for each time you get to a choice, pick the first, add to the queue the others, so you only process a path once per option but that each path would be unique

Comment: Not very helpful TJ. BugFinder I was looking at the queue system in the below answer but am struggling to convert that into a C# type scenario. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206682/finding-all-possible-paths-from-one-node-to-another?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa